# How to convert dataframe to dictionary in pandas WITHOUT index

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
| name  | coverage |
|-------|----------|
| Jason | 25.1     |
```

I want to convert it to a dictionary.
I used the following command in `pandas` :

```
dict=df.to_dict()
```

The output of `dict` gave me the following:

```
{'coverage': {0: 25.1}, 'name': {0: 'Jason'}}
```

I do not want the `0` in my output. I believe this is captured because of the column index in my dataframe `df`.
What can I do to eliminate `0` in my output
( I do not want index to be captured.) expected output :

```
{'coverage': 25.1, 'name': 'Jason'}
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

When I see your dataset with 2 columns I see a series and not a dataframe.

Try this: `d = df.set_index('name')['coverage'].to_dict()` which will convert your dataframe to a series and output that.

However, if your intent is to have more columns and not a common key you could store them in an array instead using 'records'. `d = df.to_dict('r')`.
`

Runnable code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Jason'],
    'coverage': [25.1]
})

print(df.to_dict())
print(df.set_index('name')['coverage'].to_dict())
print(df.to_dict('records'))
```

Returns:

```
{'name': {0: 'Jason'}, 'coverage': {0: 25.1}}
{'Jason': 25.1}
[{'name': 'Jason', 'coverage': 25.1}]
```

And one more thing, try to avoid to use variable name dict as it is reserved.

Updated 2013-11-01. Now use 'records' instead of 'r' thanks to comment.

Comment: df.to_dict('r') no longer seems to work. It raises ValueError(f"orient '{orient}' not understood"). df.to_dict('records') does seem to produce results (as other answers have said)

Answer (score 103):

```
dict1 = df.to_dict('records')
```

or

```
dict2 = df.to_dict('list')
```

`list`: keys are column names, values are lists of column data

`records`: each row becomes a dictionary where key is column name and value is the data in the cell

Answer (score 9):

you can do something like this:

```
data.to_dict('list')

#output:
#{'Feeling low in energy-slowed down': [2, 4, 2, 4]}
```

Answer (score 1):

if its just 1 column, slice the 1 column (it gets converted to Series) wrapping in a dict function

```
dict( myDF.iloc[:, -1] )
# [: , -1] means: return all rows, return last column)

{Jason: 25.1}
```

Answer (score -1):

zip should be another choice
dict=dict(zip(df['name'],df['coverage']))

Comment: The goal is to use column labels as dictionary keys, which this does not do.